# Error when calling R from Pandas

Tags: pandas, rpy2

I just follow this tutorial : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/r_interface.html
when I type :

```
import pandas.rpy.common as com
```

it gives below error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\pandas\rpy\common.py", line 11, in <module>
    from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
ImportError: No module named packages
```

How to fix it ?

Pandas 0.8.1 + Python 2.6 + R 2.12.2 + rpy2 2.0.8 + window-xp

Comment: On [that page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/r_interface.html) it suggests "rpy2 (> 2.2)", is it possible for you to upgrade and try again?